# ¿Cómo acceder al valor de una variable local de una funcion por fuera de ella?

Tags: php

¿Cómo podría acceder al valor de una variable que se ha declarado dentro de una función (la cual sería de tipo local)?

```
function calcularNumero(){
  $variable_local = 'Local';
}
```

Con la finalidad de acceder de la siguiente manera y poder imprimirla con un `echo`:

```
function calcularNumero(){
  $variable_local = 'Local';
}
echo "Valor: ". $variable_local
```

Y evitar de esta manera la siguiente observación que estoy obteniendo:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: variable_local in C:\Users\Johan
>   Corrales\Documents\GitHub\angular\api\Class\PDF2\currency.php on line
>   7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es retornarla y obtenerla a través de una variable así:

```
<?php

function calcularNumero()
{
  $variable_local = 'Local';
  return $variable_local;
}

$variable_local = calcularNumero();
echo "Valor: ", $variable_local;

?>
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20calcularNumero()%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20$variable_local%20=%20'Local';%5Cn%20return%20$variable_local;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn$variable_local%20=%20calcularNumero();%5Cnecho%20%22Valor:%20%22,%20$variable_local;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Comment: Gracias, ha servido correctamente!